# What's the difference between stub_model and mock_model in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

What's the difference between `stub_model` and `mock_model` in RSpec? So far, I know that stubs are used to just prevent the real method from being called and return a predefined value, and mocks are actually expectations and require that the method is called on the receiver.

I also know that these stubs/mocks are used to allow isolated testing, such as in controllers without touching the model. But I'm still confused with these two methods, when exactly are each used? Details and examples would be very much appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure if this applies to your question but one thing helpful for me was realizing that rspec "mocks" were for creating fake objects while "stubs" were for creating fake methods. Notice I'm not talking about `stub_model` or `mock_model` but the more generic terms of mock and stub.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## stub_model

> The `stub_model` method generates an instance of a Active Model model.
>
> While you can use `stub_model` in any example (model, view, controller, helper), it is especially useful in view examples, which are inherently more state-based than interaction-based.

## mock_model

> The `mock_model` method generates a **test double** that acts like an Active Model
>   model. This is different from the `stub_model` method which generates an instance of a real ActiveModel class.
>
> The benefit of `mock_model` over `stub_model` is that its a true double, so the examples are not dependent on the behaviour (or mis-behaviour), or even the existence of any other code. 
>   If you're working on a controller spec and you need a model that doesn't exist, you can pass `mock_model` a string and the generated object will act as though its an instance of the class named by that string.

rspec docs: [stub_model](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-4/docs/mocks/stub-model) and [mock_model](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-4/docs/mocks/mock-model)